# Joining only particular dates with DateListPlot

Tags: plotting

I have the following datasets:

```
dataset1={{{1997}, 98/79}, {{1998}, 26/61}, {{1999}, 22/15}, {{2000}, 100/
  63}, {{2007}, 284/57}, {{2008}, 226/31}, {{2009}, 15/4}, {{2010}, 
  221/63}};

dataset2={{{1997}, 25/79}, {{1998}, 17/61}, {{1999}, 28/25}, {{2000}, 20/
  21}, {{2007}, 106/57}, {{2008}, 128/31}, {{2009}, 59/16}, {{2010}, 
  32/9}};
```

I want to plot them using `DateListPlot[{dataset1,dataset2}]` (plus appropriate additions, such as `Joined`, etc.). Note, however, that there is a missing gap here: the years 2001 through 2006. I have multiple datasets (over five of them) so the dots can be hard to understand. If I use the `Filling->Bottom` addition, it cleans it up a bit, but still a bit hard. If I use `Joined->true`, it just connects 2000 and 2007 (as it should) but this implies data that I don't have.

Is there a way, using *Mathematica*, to connect the points for the years 1997 through 2000 and the years 2007 through 2010 - but not to draw a line in the middle between 2000 and 2007, as that skews the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add in a `Null` data point to each series like this:

```
dataset1 = {{{1997}, 98/79}, {{1998}, 26/61}, {{1999}, 
    22/15}, {{2000}, 100/63}, {{2001}, Null}, {{2007}, 
    284/57}, {{2008}, 226/31}, {{2009}, 15/4}, {{2010}, 221/63}};

dataset2 = {{{1997}, 25/79}, {{1998}, 17/61}, {{1999}, 
    28/25}, {{2000}, 20/21}, {{2001}, Null}, {{2007}, 
    106/57}, {{2008}, 128/31}, {{2009}, 59/16}, {{2010}, 32/9}};
```

The plot then becomes:

```
DateListPlot[{dataset1, dataset2}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if this works in general for, say `ListPlot`?

Comment: @tkott Yes, it does.

Comment: You could add a function like this `parseList[list_, threshold_] := Module[{tag},
  Reap[ Fold[(If[Abs@DateDifference[First@#2, First@#1] > threshold, Sow[{First@#1, Null}, tag]]; Sow[#2, tag]) &, First@list, Rest@list], tag][[2 , 1]]]` to parse the list, where threshold is given in days

Comment: unrelated, but looking at the plot above I want to remind everybody about the option GridLines->False, which together with Frame->{True,True,False,False}, allow Edward Tufte to sleep at night.